# Dropped Dell XPS has hard-drive trouble

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, bsod, dell-xps

Yesterday, my mom dropped her laptop to the floor and got the blue screen of death after trying to boot the system.

I was able to start a Fedora live CD and get some of her stuff off the hard drive, but I cannot seem to be able to install Windows on it. The installation starts loading files and then the computer turns off.

I am thinking that she might need  a new hard drive.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
I actually was able to boot the Windows XP installation but it is saying that no hard disk is detected. How can this be possible if I was able to mount the drive on fedora yesterday?

Comment: Did the harddrive make any weird sounds? Also, have you tried "fully" reformatting it and checking if it has bad sectors?

Comment: Haven't tried that... What tools would you recommend to perform sector checking?

Comment: I am actually starting to think that it is also an overheating problem... was running diagnostics and the computer suddenly turns off

Comment: yeah, the sudden power-off could be an overheating problem.  possibly the drop knocked a heatsink loose.  time to disassemble the laptop and inspect the innards for damage.

Answer (score 2):

If the laptop got dropped, I wouldn't be surprised if there's damage to the motherboard.

Comment: There could be damage to anything and everything - unless it's been ruggedised.

Comment: but, if the computer is turning on and I was able to use Fedora Live and get some stuff off the hard drive.... What could be the problem?

Comment: Not all damage prevents a computer from booting. As @ChrisF said, it could be just about anything. The power supply would be my next suspect.

Is it still under warranty? That may be your only hope.

Comment: Gotcha... It's not under warranty... I can format the hard drive using Gparted Live. However, when I use the WIN XP installation, it says that no hard drive was detected.

Answer (score 1):

Hey, no panicking just yet.  Here's a very likely possibility.  Since you said you are using Win XP, it could be that the motherboard hard drive controller isn't supported and therefore you need a driver before the hard drive can be accessed.  This happens a lot.

Check Dell's website for your computer and look for SATA (most likely) driver.  Get this driver, load to a USB device and try and rerun the XP installation.  During the installation process, there will be a point where it says to press (F6?) to load a disk driver.  Do so, load the driver from USB.  Then see if it will continue the installation process.

Comment: The computer worked before, and now after dropping it it doesn't work. I don't think this is a driver issue. -1

Comment: This actually makes sense since the computer was previously running on Vista. I will try installing Windows 7 after getting it.

Comment: @Alex B. - Based on you comment, you might consider up-voting this answer as the person who down-voted it seems to have been a bit hasty.

Comment: Allright. Windows Vista installation did recognize the hard drive. I installed and is working. But still has the overheating problem