# Unreadable WD My Passport Essential after dropping it

Tags: hard-drive

I accidentally dropped my 500GB WD My Passport Essential. When I plugged it to my laptop it just makes a ticking sound for a few seconds. How can I fix my Passport Essential?

Comment: Can you place your hand on it and feel it spin? If it has been dropped from a much greater height, internal physical damage may be done. You can get a replacement if it is still under warranty. Data recovery may require professional help.

Comment: See: [Hard drive makes clicking noise after being exposed to water](http://superuser.com/questions/345028/hard-drive-makes-clicking-noise-after-being-exposed-to-water) – [New Laptop hard drive is clicking](http://superuser.com/questions/181318/new-laptop-hard-drive-is-clicking) – [Hard Disk makes “Click, click, click …” noise on system start. Won't boot](http://superuser.com/questions/239424/hard-disk-makes-click-click-click-noise-on-system-start-wont-boot)

Comment: Also: [Dropped hard drive won't mount](http://superuser.com/questions/170997/dropped-hard-drive-wont-mount), [Dropped my Mac on the floor. Hard Disk doesn't work](http://superuser.com/questions/160035/dropped-my-mac-on-the-floor-hard-disk-doesnt-work), [Dropped Dell XPS has hard-drive trouble](http://superuser.com/questions/133065/dropped-dell-xps-has-hard-drive-trouble)

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely dead.  You could either send it to a data recovery service, or chalk it up to experience and buy a new one.

Comment: Might want to mention that data recovery can be several hundred dollars.  For a device that costs less then $99 many might find it not worth it.

Comment: Many data recovery companies are thousands of dollars.

Answer (score 1):

It will never, ever be reliable again. Get your data from a backup and buy a new drive.

External, portable hard drives are about the least reliable storage device ever made. They get lost, dropped, left in hot cars, and even under ideal situations they only have an expected life of about three years.